# Linking each image to the site it is from

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://weknowyourdreams.com">Family</a>
<img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/family/family-02.jpg" height="140" width="300">
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://chess.com">Chess</a>
<img height="140" width="300" alt="Chess game" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/ChessSet.jpg/647px-ChessSet.jpg">
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://okcstorm.com/index.php/basketball/">Basketball court</a>
<img src="http://okcstorm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Basketball-2-1.jpg" width="300" height="200">
```

What I want to achieve is to link them each to the site that I've got them from. But, the problem is the phone in the code avengers keep telling me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClearPromptText' of null

I don't know what that means, please help.

Comment: This is the code:

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="http://weknowyourdreams.com">Family</a> 
<img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/family/family-02.jpg" height="140" width="300">
</a>

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="http://chess.com">Chess</a>
<img  height="140" width="300" alt="Chess game" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/ChessSet.jpg/647px-ChessSet.jpg">
</a>

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="http://okcstorm.com/index.php/basketball/">Basketball court</a>
<img src="http://okcstorm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Basketball-2-1.jpg" width="300" height="200">

Comment: it's a js issue, did you have a js in your site ?

Comment: you need also to correct your code, you have a closing tag that need to be deleted

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, it's not a javascript and it doesn't involve any Java or JavaScript, only HTML, and CSS.

Comment: But it's all goods now, I just had to remove </a> as I had too much of them. Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .image-f{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  margin-right:10px;
  width:300px;
}
.image-f img{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:140;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" class="image-f" href="http://weknowyourdreams.com/" >Family
<img src="http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/family/family-02.jpg" >
</a>

<a target="_blank" class="image-f" href="http://chess.com">Chess
<img  alt="Chess game" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/ChessSet.jpg/647px-ChessSet.jpg">
</a>

<a target="_blank" class="image-f" href="http://okcstorm.com/index.php/basketball/">Basketball court
<img src="http://okcstorm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/cropped-Basketball-2-1.jpg" ></a>
```